# Swift 3 [String: AnyObject]() gives Cannot call value of non-function type UInt -> Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to append some parameters to my Alamofire request.

```
var parameters = [String: AnyObject]()

parameters["firstimg"] = fetchedImagesArray[0] as AnyObject?

parameters["secondimg"] = fetchedImagesArray[1] as AnyObject?
```

Then:

```
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
}
```

But when I try to append the parameters I get the error:
**Cannot call value of non-function type UInt -> Data**

Comment: FYI Alamofire Parameters default to `[String: Any]` not `[String: AnyObject]`

Comment: @Aaron how should I declare var parameters = [String: AnyObject]() then?

Comment: `var parameters: [String: Any]?`

Comment: what is in the `fetchedImagesArray`? Strings?

Comment: @Sam_M Yes they are strings

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `value` as `String` to use the `data(using: .utf8)` method on it:

```
if let stringValue = value as? String {
    multipartFormData.append(stringValue.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
}
```